# Error when trying to protect Excel file with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script for password protecting an Excel file.

this is the script:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)


objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Now

objWorkbook.SaveAs “C:\Test.xlsx”,,”%reTG54w”

objExcel.Quit
```

I tried running it using "run as PowerShell" but it closes automatically, I've also tried using the PowerShell ISE, the result is the one below:

[image]

the text for it is this:

```
At C:\Users\gasgu\OneDrive\Desktop\pwoershell.ps1:14 char:39
+ objWorkbook.SaveAs â€œC:\Test.xlsxâ€,,â€%reTG54wâ€
+                                       ~
Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element.
At C:\Users\gasgu\OneDrive\Desktop\pwoershell.ps1:14 char:39
+ objWorkbook.SaveAs â€œC:\Test.xlsxâ€,,â€%reTG54wâ€
+                                       ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpression
```

I've found this script from this url: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-password-protect-an-excel-spreadsheet/

But if it worth mentioning, what I'm trying to do is to pick up an Excel file from my PC (.xlsx) and password protect it (creating a new copy)  now, in  this script what I don't understand is if it's picking the excel file from somewhere as I don't see a line that explicitly says this.

Edit:  The script I was executing ended up not being PowerShell, per clarification of @BigBen (see comments and approved answer)  the script is VBS.  He provided with script in PowerShell that performs the needed result.

Comment: That looks like VBScript, not PowerShell.

Comment: you sure? in the website they mention it as powershell, as well as with other examples

Comment: Absolutely. That is not Powershell. The original question from that page dates back to 2005. I assume it was on a different site back then, or it got mistakenly migrated to a Powershell forum.

Comment: ohhh maybe we're onto something then :)  do you maybe know a way I can achieve what I need? to password protect an excel file? I'm needing to do it automatically, I'm working with SSIS and I can execute powershell, VB scripts, C# scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is VBScript, not Powershell. Perhaps try this:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Get-Date
$wb.SaveAs("C:\Test.xlsx",[Type]::Missing,"%reTG54w")
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: this generates a password protected Excel file, but how do I do for it to pick an already created Excel file and set a password to it?  (even better if it saves it as a new version)

Comment: You'll need something like `$excel.Workbooks.Open($yourfilename)` instead of `$excel.Workbooks.Add()`.

Comment: this is awesome, it even generates the new file as copy and all, thank you! :)

Comment: [Type]::Missing = XlSaveAsAccessMode

Comment: @MahmoodShehab I'm not sure where you are getting that from... The file format is an optional argument, but `XlSaveAsAccessMode` is not a valid option.

Comment: run F8, I mean execute the script line by line, and just before the wb.SaveAs,  run this command

$wb | gm | where-object {$_.name -eq "SaveAs"} | fl ,  and check the Definition

Comment: @MahmoodShehab that is the `Access Mode` argument, not the `File Format` argument. See the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas#main_) documentation.

Comment: @BigBen if you see the snapshot in the question, you will find the missing argument is XlSaveAsAccessMode

Comment: @MahmoodShehab the 2nd argument of `Workbook.SaveAs` is `FileFormat`. `expression.SaveAs (FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)`. It is optional and since the filename ends in `xlsx` I have not included it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\test\*.xlsx -Recurse
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
ForEach($File in $Files){
       try {
       $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
       $Workbook.SaveAs($File,[Type]::Missing,"1234") #password set to 1234
       $Workbook.Close($false)
       $Excel.Quit()
           }
 catch {
       }
       }
       [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
```